# I wish to see the query of the $result through an echo

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to get all the data from my users table using a query and I 
    would like to display it through an echo and this is my code please help

```
<?php
  error_reporting(0);
  require_once "helperfindercon.php";
  $user_name = "joseph";
  $user_pass = "joseph";
  $mysql_qry = "select * from users";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $mysql_qry);
  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    echo "$result"; 
  }
  else {
    echo "error";
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to apply `while()` inside `if()`(to get all records from `$result` and show them):-

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    //print_r($row);// now check the array and echo accordingly.
    foreach($row as $key=>$val){
       echo $key.' :-'.$val."\n";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: tried removing print_r and followed the echo format, and it worked
thanks alot!

Comment: @Ivann  glad to help you :):)

Comment: @AlivetoDie can I contact you thru email? or facebook so I can ask some questions

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
require_once "helperfindercon.php";
$user_name = "joseph";
$user_pass = "joseph";
$mysql_qry = "select * from users";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $mysql_qry);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
   printt_r($result);   // should use print_r as its type of array
}
else {
echo "error";
}  
?>
```

Comment: it just shows a blank space